# Automatically show string on form open

Tags: c#, string, textbox

I have two forms, the main opens a second form prior to main loading.

On this secondary form I have a textbox to display the logged in username for Windows.

I want this username to show in the textbox when then form opens but currently it only displays when clicking into the textbox and pressing down the spacebar.

I have tried changing the onclick stuff but closet I got was having it load when the cursor went over it.

How can I have the textbox show the username onload or would a label be a better idea?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chat
{
    public partial class loginForm : Form
    {
        public loginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userName = Environment.UserName;
            usernametextBox.Text = (userName);
        }

        private void userloginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Run(new chatForm());

            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void usernametextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Use `Form_Load` or it's constructor.

Comment: Use formload form event not texbox textchanging event

Comment: In a new form this works, in the current it does not.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of places where you can initialize the value of a textbox.

One common place would be the Form's constructor.

Something like

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Environment.UserName;
    usernametextBox.Text = (userName);
}
```

That would be the constructor of the second form, the one that contains the text box.

You can also pass the value to the second form via a constructor parameter or public function if you want the first form to be in charge of prepopulating the username value of the second form after creating it.

Comment: I have tried this and still have to click into the textbox and hit spacebar to get the result.

Comment: Can you post the complete code for your second form?
I have tested this solution and it works.
For testing purposes, try creating a brand new project, just add one textbox, set it's text value in the constructor of the form, and see if that works. It really should. Then we can start hunting your bug elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Sure, question edited to show full code as requested.

Comment: Unless you have declared the textbox as public and are calling it's methods from outside this form, the code you have pasted should work.

Is the textbox properly sized? Does the text fit ? Is it multiline?

I am suspecting either weird textbox / font settings, making the text visible only after focusing/editing the textbox.
Or possibly rendering/graphics issues on your machine.

Please create a blank project with one textbox and set it's value in the constructor, see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working as intended with a label over textbox using this solution.  Good shout!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but it's relly not a proper solution. if you added a label over a textbox, that is simply a hack to hide the real problem. You should probably find out what the actual problem is and fix it. As said, I suggest you start with a blank project to see if it works fine there. Then you can continue searching for the cause of the error.

Comment: No no, in the new form it worked.  I switched to label as the textbox remain highlighted when running. but the issue remains in the new form, it shows nothing in the label or textbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Environment.UserName;
    usernametextBox.Text = userName;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and still have to click into the textbox and hit spacebar to get the result.

Comment: In a new form this works, in the current it does not.  Any advice?

Comment: Are you able to check whether this method is invoking?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to load username on form loading then you should go with FormLoad event of form

or

if you want to load username on focus of textbox then you should go with GotFocus event

Comment: In a new form this works, in the current it does not.  Any advice?